# 0 Есть ли альтернатива preg_match php для c#

Tags: c#

Есть ли альтернатива preg_match php для c#, помогите пожалуйста (лучше с примером).
И что бы парсило именно значения между <uid></uid> (html). 
Попробовал вот так, но что-то не робит

```
string text = "<token>slon</token><uid>2141</uid><aut>12:11:32</aut>";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\<uid>(.*?)</\uid>\");
    Match match = regex.Match(text);
    while (match.Success)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(match.Index.ToString() + " " +
                     match.Value);
     match = match.NextMatch();
    }
```

Comment: >@"\<uid>(.*?)</\uid>\"

Зачем вы экранируете все подряд, используя конструкцию с собакой? Вы понимаете, что после последнего обратного слеша символа нет?

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте из вашего текста подобие XML и вперед:

```
string text = "<token>slon</token><uid>2141</uid><aut>12:11:32</aut>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<root>" + text + "</root>");
var entries = from elem in xdoc.Descendants("uid") select elem.Value;
```